# Does the order of include functions of jquery and jquery mobile matters?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

If I use this order:

```
<script src="jsv3/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="jsv3/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jsv3/turn.min.js"></script>
<script src="jsv3/onload_mobile.js"></script>
<script src="jsv3/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="jsv3/jquery.viewport.min.js"></script>
<script src="jsv3/jquery.scraggable.js"></script>
```

Return Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'match'

(Type error: c.match is not a function using FireBugs error report)

If I use this order

```
<script src="jsv3/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jsv3/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="jsv3/turn.min.js"></script>
<script src="jsv3/onload_mobile.js"></script>
<script src="jsv3/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="jsv3/jquery.viewport.min.js"></script>
<script src="jsv3/jquery.scraggable.js"></script>
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mobile' of undefined

(Type error: a is undefined using FireBugs error report)

According to official website , the order is the first one, however, the first one seems display nothing while the second one is function properly for my case. Is using second order is correct, also, why is this error occur? Is it due to I use desktop browser to view the page? Sorry for newible to mobile web development, thanks

Comment: im not sure about this, but have you tried put <script src="jsv3/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script> under the jquery-1.8.3.js?

Comment: Thanks , if I use jquery, jquery ui, jquery mobile it returns no error, however, it show a blank page without the background and all functions not working properly

Comment: Same problem here too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181610/jquery-vs-jquery-mobile-does-the-script-sequence-matter

So what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to conflict between jquery mobile and jquery ui

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
This is the order that I have now and works correctly

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```