# jQuery vs jQuery Mobile - Does the script sequence matter?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I do not know why but it seems to cause some problem when i include the script in a different sequence.

When it is this way:

```
    <script src="static/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

my program works! Fiddle works too : http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/MKfLU/4/
but the css theme for jQuery mobile doesnt work anymore on my web app.

When it is this way:

```
    <script src="static/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

It doesn't work and gave me "undefined" for variable "textInput", even on Fiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/7NZzr/

Can someone tell me why? :(

Comment: jquerymobile stuff on http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/7NZzr/ is working for me.

Comment: how come? :( it gave me "undefined"  i'm using firefox here.

Comment: i only have chrome on this station, and its working fine here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand this problem you need to understand how jQuery Mobile works.

Initialization order is not a problem in your second example. If it were a problem all those elements would not be styled. In your case, what you dont know is, when jQuery Mobile styles form elements it changes their DOM structure. So button and input elements are no longer at the same place like in your non-styled first example.

This is a fix to your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FmPPW/

Change this:

```
$('.TextInput').empty();
textInput = $(this).prev('.TextInput').val();
```

to this:

```
$('.TextInput').empty();
textInput = $(this).parent().prev().find('.TextInput').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for "Configuring Defaults" talks about the mobileinit event:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html

> Because the mobileinit event is triggered immediately upon execution,
>   you'll need to bind your event handler before jQuery Mobile is loaded.
>   Thus, we recommend linking to your JavaScript files in the following
>   order:
>
> ```
> <script src="jquery.js"></script>
> <script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
> <script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
> ```

The quickstart guide shows a page template with the same order: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/about/getting-started.html

It appears that jquery needs to be loaded in order for jquery-mobile to work.

Comment: however it doesn't work for me when i put in that sequence... any idea why?

Comment: i still do not know exactly what is happening and how to solve it :( could you please explain a bit more?